# Variables in Spring Data JPA native query

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Using Spring Dat JPA, I need to query my database and return a range of `OrderEntity`s based on a `startAmt` and a `endAmt` of amounts.  I'm not sure if I should map these two variables to entity `OrderEntity`, as fields in some type of separate class/entity/model, or simply declare them in my native query. Perhaps I should be using a service that implements `EntityManager.createNativeQuery()`?

Would like to do something like :

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRangeRepository extends JpaRepository<OrderEntity, OrderEntityID> {

        @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE Amount BETWEEN startAmt AND endAmt;" , nativeQuery=true)
    List<OrderEntity> findOrdersBy(int startAmt, int endAmt);

}
```

If I were to use `EntityManager.createNativeQuery()` in a service, perhaps something like below :

```
@Service
public class OrderRangeService {

    @Autowired
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<OrderEntity> findAmountsBetween() {

        List<OrderEntity> amountsBetween = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE Amount BETWEEN ?1 AND 2?;")
        .setParameter(1, "startAmt")
        .setParameter(2, "endAmt")
        .getResultList();

        return amountsBetween;


    }

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve this with Spring Data JPA without defining a native query.

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRangeRepository extends JpaRepository<OrderEntity, OrderEntityID> {
    List<OrderEntity> findByAmountBetween(int startAmt, int endAmt);
}
```

If you want to use the native query change it to

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE Amount BETWEEN :startAmt AND :endAmt" , nativeQuery=true)
List<OrderEntity> findOrdersBy(@Param("startAmt") int startAmt, @Param("endAmt") int endAmt);
```

You can invoke the query in a service by doing

```
@Service
public class OrderRangeService {

    @Autowired
    OrderRangeRepository orderRangeRepository ;

    public List<OrderEntity> findAmountsBetween(int startAmt, int endAmt) {
        List<OrderEntity> amountsBetween = orderRangeRepository.findByAmountBetween(startAmt, endAmt);
        return amountsBetween;
    }

}
```

Finally, from your controller, you should autowire the OrderRangeService and invoke the findAmountsBetween service method

```
@Autowired
OrderRangeService orderRangeService;

@GetMapping("/amountsFromAndTo")
@ResponseBody
public String getAmounts(@RequestParam int startAmt, @RequestParam int endAmt) {
    List<OrderEntity> orderEntityL = orderRangeService.findAmountsBetween(startAmt, endAmt);
    return orderEntityL.toString();
}
```

Comment: --Using `findByAmountBetween(1,2)` results in a query with numbers between 1 & 2.  How could I make this work from the HTTP Query String such as in `http://localhost:8080/amountsFromAndTo?startAmt=1000&endAmt=2000` please?And I'm using your second example, native query.

Comment: The 1,2 was an example to show how to pass the from-to between values. You can replace the 1,2 with int variables. I have updated my answer (second example). You should pass these variables from your controller to the service and to JPA repository

Answer (score 8):

**1. Named Parameters**

> Each parameter annotated with @Param must have a value string matching
>   the corresponding JPQL or SQL query parameter name. A query with named
>   parameters is easier to read and is less error-prone in case the query
>   needs to be refactored.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE Amount BETWEEN :startAmt AND :endAmt;" , nativeQuery=true)
List<OrderEntity> findOrdersBy(@Param("startAmt") int startAmt, @Param("endAmt") int endAmt);

}
```

**2. Indexed Query Parameters**

> Spring Data will pass method parameters to the query in the same order
>   they appear in the method declaration

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE Amount BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2;" , nativeQuery=true)
List<OrderEntity> findOrdersBy(int startAmt, int endAmt);
```