# How to integrate variable in native sql query in Spring Data

Tags: sql, spring, postgresql, spring-data

Tables

```
 @Data
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "A")
 class A {
    private Long id;
    private Long bId;
 }

 @Data
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "B")
 class B {
    private Long id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Status status;
 }

enum Status {
NEW,
VALIDATED,
ARCHIVE
}
```

I have a following native query

```
@Query(value = "SELECT cast(a.id as varchar) FROM a
INNER JOIN b on a.id = b.id
WHERE a.id = :id AND
b.status = 'NEW'", // here I need smth like b.status = '" + Status.NEW + "' ",
nativeQuery = true)
Set<UUID> findIdByStatuses(@Param UUID id)
```

Instead of b.status = 'NEW', I need smth like
b.status = '" + Status.NEW + "' ",

to get a compile error when name of Status changes. But it is not working like this.
And the question is how to reach that desirable concatenation inside of native query without method argumetns

Comment: how about having enum method toString()? Status.NEW.toString()

Comment: Did not work either. Now I started thinking that I can integrate my variables only through @Param in method arguments

Comment: Please see if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58453768/variables-in-spring-data-jpa-native-query can solve your problem.