# how to pass value to LIKE statement in jpa native query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

Here, I'm trying to pass string parameter value to native query which has like command in JPA Repository

```
@Query(value = "select u.* from users where u.name like '%?1%'",nativeQuery = true)
List<User> findAllByNameContaining(String searchString);
```

When I tried to debug with show sql flag. I see, below result in console

```
Hibernate: 
/* dynamic native SQL query */ select
    u.* 
from
    users u 
join
    customer c 
        on u.id = c.userId 
where
    c.trainerId = ? 
    and u.name like '%?2%'
```

I'm assing its adding extra single quote (i.e) like **'%'searchvalue'%'**

Note : Query is more complex than mentioned here. so, I don't want solutions like findAllByNameContaining or findByNameIgnoreCaseContaining etc...

Comment: I hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/58454092/4655217

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it work by prepending and appending % in search string and passing it as below

```
@Query(value = "select u.* from users where u.name like ?1",nativeQuery = true)
List<User> findAllByNameContaining(String searchString);
```

Calling it by

```
List<Users> result = userRepository.findAllByNameContaining("%".concat(searchString).concat("%"));
```

Answer (score 0):

No use `nativeQuery = true` with jpql

Use Like keyword :

```
List<User> findByNameLike(String searchString);
```

Also you can try this

```
@Query(value = "select u.* from users where u.name like %:searchString%")
```

Comment: As I mentioned in question, the actual query is more complex than that. So, I need a way to add like in native query itself

Answer (score 0):

When you put `'%?2%'` in the query that doesn't expand to a parameter that gets concatenated with `%` on both sides. You can't put parameters **inside** a string literal.